# Imagemagick/convert monochromatic tiff file into monochromatic png file

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have a tiff file that is monochromatic. It's just black and white pixels.

When I use `identify` (part of imagemagick) I get this output:

```
filename.tif TIFF 7300x5536 7300x5536+0+0 1-bit Bilevel DirectClass 1.854MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

I want to convert this to a png file (to display on the web), so I do `convert filename.tif filename.png`, however when I `identify` this file, I get:

```
1577.png PNG 7300x5536 7300x5536+0+0 8-bit PseudoClass 2c 1.669MB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

i.e. it reports as 8-bit image (right?)

How can I force this into a 2 bit image?

My goal is to reduce the filesize as much as possible (without losing quality), and i think that if it's 2 bits per pixel, it'll use less space.

**Update**: I have already tried the following options (on their own): `-depth 2`, `-colors 2`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can try with:

```
convert -colors 2 filename.tif filename.png
```

From Imagemagic documentation ( http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#colors )

Comment: I just tried "convert.exe 1.tif -colors 2 2.tif" and it worked properly for me, converting an 8-bit TIFF to a 1-bit TIFF   Not sure if the difference is the target format or the order of the options.

Comment: Just for reference: -colors 2 reduces the numbers of colors but still uses the default 8 bit color space (for grayscale). What you need is flag `-monochrome` like this:  `convert -monochrome filename.tif out.tiff` (note that for PNG output the colorspace is still 8 bit though)